# Mobile keyboard does not open with Javascript focus event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cross-browser, jquery-events

Trying to focus a simple input text when page loads with Javascript events, my goal is to focus and open the virtual keyboard on mobile browsers but I've not gotten success.

My code looks like so simple as:

```
document.getElementById("anser-animation").focus();
document.getElementById("anser-animation").click();
```

I've tried on jQuery as well...

```
$('#answer-animation').focus();
$('#answer-animation').trigger('click');
```

On android input gets focus but not on iPhones. On both cases I don't get the keyboard intermediately on page loading. I'm not sure what's more I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge. That is because Apple has decided to disable this functionality, when bind with `$(document).ready(function (){});`

What you could do (if target-page is reached via Ajax and/or if it's applicable in your case) is that when a button is pressed, i.e ("sign up") is trigger `focus();` on the input field.

Like this:

```
$(".sign-up-button").click(function (){
    $(".first_name").focus();
});
```

This is at least how I've solved it in the past, but if this won't work for you, then I'm sorry, but you're just out of luck, like so many of us. For now at least.

Answer (score -1):

You have you do like this

```
$("#fname").trigger('focus');
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it is supposed to solve the problem.